# Update item on TodoList Angularfire

Tags: javascript, firebase, angularfire, firebase-realtime-database

Using Angularfire, i create todoList. But i have a problem in updating items. I try this code

```
 var obj = $firebaseObject(ref);
 obj.name = $scope.todo.title ;
 obj.$save()
  .then(function(ref) {
    ref.key() === obj.$id; // true
  }, function(error) {
    console.log("Error:", error);
  });
```

How can i update only the selected item.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
var obj = $firebaseObject(ref);
obj.$loaded().then(function () {
    obj.name = $scope.todo.title;
    obj.$save()
        .then(function (ref) {
            ref.key() === obj.$id; // true
        }, function (error) {
            console.log("Error:", error);
        });
});
```

You are trying to save it before it's been loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can also simply update the TODO item's title directly, without going through `$firebaseObject()`:

```
ref.update({ title: $scope.todo.title });
```

The `$firebaseObject()` and `$firebaseArray()` services are great for binding the underlying data to Angular views, but to perform an update to the data you can just as easily take the more direct approach. Since AngularFire is built on top of the Firebase JavaScript SDK, they interoperate perfectly.

Comment: thank u for Sir, but i have to use angularfire because it's a part of a mini projet that i must use only angularfire. My problem is that i don't find the best way to update nly the selected item.

Comment: Since AngularFire is built on top of the Firebase JavaScript SDK, you cannot use AngularFire without also using the Firebase JavaScript SDK.